# unexpected result in numpy array slicing (view vs copy)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, slice

I'm trying to reduce the amount of copying in my code and I came across surprising behavior when dealing with numpy array slicing and views, as explained in:

[Scipy wiki page on copying numpy arrays](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-1529ae93dd5d431ffe3a1001a4ab1a394e70a5f2)

I've stumbled across the following behavior, which is unexpected for me:

**Case 1.:**

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones((3,3))
b = a[:,1:2]
b += 5
print a
print b.base is a
```

As expected, this outputs:

```
array([[ 1.,  6.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  6.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  6.,  1.]])
True
```

**Case 2:** When performing the slicing and addition in one line, things look different:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones((3,3))
b = a[:,1:2] + 5
print a
print b.base is a
```

The part that's surprising to me is that a[:,1:2] does not seem to create a view, which is then used as a left hand side argument, so, this outputs:

```
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
False
```

Maybe someone can shed some light on why these two cases are different, I think I'm missing something.

**Solution**: I missed the obvious fact that the "+" operator, other than the in-place operator "+=" will always create a copy, so it's in fact not related but slicing other than how in-place operators are defined for numpy arrays.

To illustrate this, the following generates the same output as Case 2:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones((3,3))
b = a[:,1:2]
b = b + 5
print a
print b.base is a
```

Comment: If both results are "as expected", what are you confused about?

Comment: updated my question, the results from case 2 is unexpected, I would it expect to be the same as case 1.

Comment: The slice still creates a view; it's `+` that creates a new array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above is no different than:

```
>>> a=np.arange(5)
>>> b=a
>>> b
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

>>> b+=5
>>> a
array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> b
array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

>>> b=b+5
>>> b
array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
>>> a
array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Which, at least to me, seem like completely expected behavior. The `b+=x` operator calls `__iadd__` which importantly first tries to modify the array in place, so it will *update* `b` which is still a view of `a`. While the `b=b+x` operator calls `__add__` which creates new temporary data and then *assigns* it to `b`.

For `a[i] +=b` the sequence is (in numpy):

```
a.__setitem__(i, a.__getitem__(i).__iadd__(b))
```

Answer (score 2):

`a[:, 1:2]` creates a view, but you don't modify the view in the second example. Instead, `+` creates a new array from its arguments. Suppose you do

```
a = np.ones((3, 3))
b = a + 5
```

In that case, you wouldn't expect a change to `a`, because this isn't an in-place addition. The operator is `+`, rather than `+=`. It's the same with the second example.

```
b = a[:, 1:2] + 5
```

doesn't modify `a[:, 1:2]`, because this isn't in-place addition.

Answer (score 1):

The default thing to do when slicing a numpy array is to create b as a view of a, thus when you change b, a changes as well, which is confirmed by your first case.

The second case is more tricky. You are not telling that b is a slice of a and then adding a number. What you are doing is creating b as something that does not coincide with a, so numpy is forced to copy the data instead of just creating a view.